# 'A' transpose inverse equals to 'B' transpose

Tags: matrices

I searched everywhere but I could not find a solution to this problem.

Let $A$ and $B$ be invertible matrices with $AB = I$. Show that

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to spoil anything, I leave you to prove that $(A^t)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^t$, whenever that makes sense. With this result, we have: $$AB = I \implies A^{-1} = B \implies (A^{-1})^t = B^t \implies (A^{-1})^t = B^t.$$

Comment: are you sure if we can change the powers?? cos $2^2^3 =! 2^3^2$ *confused*

Comment: $A$ is a matrix, not a number (unless you think of a $1 \times 1$ matrix). The point is that matrices behave differently than numbers. For example, multiplication of matrices is not commutative (it can happen that $AB \neq BA$). And $t$ is the transpose operation, it is **not** $A$ raised to some power $t$;

Comment: I got its prove, thanks! yes they are equal

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Note: $\left(A^T\right)^{-1} = \left(A^{-1}\right)^T$.

Comment: are you sure if we can change the powers?? cos $2^2^3 =! 2^3^2$ *confused*

Comment: $\left(\cdot\right)^T$ is not a power. It is the transpose operator.

Comment: Ya, that's right. But are you sure they are equal? cos they don't seems like equal :/

Comment: I got its prove, thanks! yes they are equal

Comment: Yes, I am sure that this identity is true. It is easy to verify. Noting that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$, we have $$I=\left(A^{T}\right)^{-1}A^T = \left(A^{-1}\right)^TA^T = AA^{-1}.$$